# jquery autoComplete with List<string> as Source

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, ajaxpro

i have text box name txtEmailList, i provided autocomplete list for it,

```
 <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtEmailList" CssClass="txtAutoComplete">
```

script for autocomplete

```
$('#txtEmailList').autocomplete({
                source: function(request, response) {
// this is the ajax call, which is running successfully
                    var msg = 
Assessments_JqueryAutoComplete.AutoComplete(request.term).value; //(ajaxpro functions)
                    response(msg.d); 
                }

            });
```

output  will come as like this (in firebug it shows as plain/text), how can i attach this array to source property.  ( i cant use $.ajax method, as i need to use ajaxpro as office rules), so i get the list of array back from ajax call, how do i bind the autocomplete.

> ["List 1","List 2","List 3","List 4"];/*   // this is the output response from jquery( from firebug)

```
[AjaxPro.AjaxMethod(HttpSessionStateRequirement.ReadWrite)]
public List<string> AutoComplete(string query)
{
List<string> objLisItmes = new List<string>();
objLisItmes.Add("List 1");
objLisItmes.Add("List 2");
objLisItmes.Add("List 3");
objLisItmes.Add("List 4");
return  objLisItmes;
}
```

this is the firebug output in for Response headers

> Cache-Controlno-cache Content-Length40 Content-Typetext/plain; 
>   charset=utf-8 DateWed, 07 Mar 2012 10:45:37 GMT
>   Expires-1Pragmano-cache

Comment: I guess you need to return what you get from the server...

Comment: how ?  i already tried response(msg.d) but it is not showing in autocomplete

Comment: no... Write this: `return msg;`

Comment: i tried returning msg, but no success ;(

Comment: can you show the html for the textbox also?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of returning a List. I would return a string Array as:

```
[AjaxPro.AjaxMethod(HttpSessionStateRequirement.ReadWrite)]
public string[] AutoComplete(string query)
{
   List<string> objLisItmes = new List<string>();
   objLisItmes.Add("List 1");
   objLisItmes.Add("List 2");
   objLisItmes.Add("List 3");
   objLisItmes.Add("List 4");
   return  objLisItmes.ToArray();
}
```

Comment: what will change ? will it help, by returning array ? how it will help ?

Comment: List<string> should work fine, and appears to be since you say you're getting back the list of items. Can you show the html for the textbox?

Comment: thank you :) any way it works. now, but i am not getting the idea why ToArray() is needed here ?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using

```
$('#txtEmailList')
```

try using

```
$('input[id$="txtEmailList"]')
```

Since you are using a server control TextBox your ID for it is most likely ending up as something like "parentID1_parentID2_txtEmailList". The above code will grab the input that has an ID that ends with "txtEmailList".

Here's how I am doing it in my test project and it is working. Of course I'm not using AjaxPro, so I am not sure exactly how you would do it with that instead, but maybe it will give you some ideas.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            var element = $('input[id$="TextBox1"]');

            element.autocomplete({
                source: function (request, response) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "Default.aspx/GetList",
                        data: "{ 'term': '" + request.term + "' }",
                        dataType: "json",
                        type: "POST",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        dataFilter: function(data) { return data; },
                        success: function (data) {
                            response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                                return {
                                    value: item
                                }
                            }))
                        }
                    })
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: what is the diff ? as i am accessing it directly.  ? i think this is not the answer. even its comming in open function of jquery autocomplete

Comment: its not in grid view. to render like that. its in plain textbox in a div, even i checked the render id, it is same as what i gave in the jquery selector. so issue will be with the response type i guess

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't it be:

```
$('#txtEmailList').autocomplete({source: function(request, response) {
    // this is the ajax call, which is running successfully
    var msg = Assessments_JqueryAutoComplete.AutoComplete(request.term).value; //(ajaxpro functions)
    response(msg); 
    }

});
```

?

If not, I would suggest you use console.log(msg) to analyse the response object if possible.

Answer (score 1):

Just make sure your AJAX call is returning *valid string format* like this [dummy example](http://jsfiddle.net/LcqXN/1/).
Store it in a variable.
Then use it to define `source` property like this :

```
var availableValues = ["List 1","List 2","List 3","List 4"];
// var msg = Assessments_JqueryAutoComplete.AutoComplete(request.term).value;
$( "#txtEmailList" ).autocomplete({
    source: availableValues
});
```